# Adding a Table in a PDF Document

Tags: android, build.gradle, pdf-generation

I've created a PDF document using an android studio. But it contains only text. I want to insert a table into it. Because it is a report that needs to be downloaded from my app as a pdf. I looked at each and every tutorial, but all uses iText. iText 7 works out of the box when used on a device with an Android API level 24 or higher (Android Nougat). I even tried to add iText in gradle files. But still no use.

Document, PdfPTable, Paragraph. All of such keywords are in red color show **Can not Resolve Symbol**. 
I am using Android Studio 3.5.0.0 version. Can anyone suggest me a solution?

I've created the pdf document using the following code that is properly working.

```
    PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
    PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(300, 600, 1).create();

    PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);
    Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);


    //canvas.drawtext in the page
    canvas.drawText(sometext, 80, 50, paint);

    // finish the page
    document.finishPage(page);
```

---

```
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.pdf.PdfDocument;
```

are used to do the above code.